# VSCode TypeScript intellisense takes forever to load remotely

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, file-watcher

Every time I connect to **Remote** Linux Server via VSCode, there's a notification popping up - Initializing JS/TS language features.  The relevant extension to this is probably "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features".  I think I would probably need this extension for intellisense to work properly (unless if any of y'all can suggest any other alternatives).

It takes forever. (It's almost instant if I run VSCode locally)

I think the issue lies on having FileWatcher and DirectoryWatcher taking forever to load for big files/folders such as node_modules.

I would like to exclude node_modules properly.  This is what I have tried to implement in ./.vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "files.watcherExclude": {
        "/**/node_modules/*/**": true,
        "/**/node_modules": true,
        "/home/abc/a/**": true,
        "/home/abc/b/node_modules": true,
        "/home/abc/b/node_modules/*/**": true
    }
}
```

But according to tsserver.log:

```
Info 111  [10:34:23.652] DirectoryWatcher:: Added:: WatchInfo: /home/abc/b/node_modules 1 undefined WatchType: node_modules for closed script infos and package.jsons affecting module specifier cache
```

VSCode is still watching node_modules and it takes decades for the next lines to appear...

After 10 minutes:

```
Info 112  [11:16:39.533] Elapsed:: 675488.8780369759ms DirectoryWatcher:: Added:: WatchInfo: /home/abc/b/node_modules 1 undefined WatchType: node_modules for closed script infos and package.jsons affecting module specifier cache
```

What's the approach to properly disabling FileWatcher and DirectoryWatcher for node_modules?